# Insert row after Specific no of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a list of candidates and i need to insert a row after a name which i will select after drop down in another cell.

Let's say i have 5 candidates a, b,c, d,e and I select candidate b in the dropdown I need a VBA code to insert row under candidate brow.

```
Sub Match()
Range("C9").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C8").Value, Range("B1:B1000"), 0)
```

I have a drop down in cell c8 and i have a list of the name in the column now i am where i can find where is that text but i am unable to insert a row under it please help

Answer (score 0):

This should do It:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Match()

    Dim MyRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your sheet name
        MyRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(.Range("C8").Value, .Range("B1:B1000"), 0) + 1
        .Rows(MyRow).Insert
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @sandeepjadhav Glad it helped, don't forget to mark it as correct so others might find it.